Tree View Kendo Fill dataTextField
I have a Treeview kendo in my code. it is populated via the following.
My question is that I don't know what the column names are to put in the dataTextField.
Can anyone help me?
ds = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: baseApiAddr + 'a/GetPYITree',
            datatype: 'json',
            type: 'GET'
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: 'Id',
            hasChildren: 'HasChildren'
        }
    }
});


$.kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: ds,
    loadOnDemand: true,
    dataTextField: ??,
    change: function () {
        treeViewClick();
    }
});

How can I find the column's name of ds?
